# C# JSON deserialization: can I intercept the deserialization and optionally change the result?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

We've got some JSON that we are deserializing into a strongly-typed object graph in C#.  However, we've got one issue: sometimes there is an "empty" value in the JSON (e.g., empty string) in a property that maps to a boolean value in our model.

In our case, we know that 100% of the time, we can translate these "blank" values to Boolean `false`.

However, the JSON deserializers I've tried don't know about this (understandably).

I've been trying to find a way to intercept the deserialization of each property, and optionally override the output.  I.e., if there was an "interceptor" method I could register, that looked like this:

```
    public Boolean JsonDeserializationInterceptor(String rawJson, System.Type targetType, out object result)
    {
        Boolean overrodeValue = false;
        result = null;
        if(targetType == typeof(System.Boolean))
        {
            overrodeValue = true;
            // We'll pretend that we're interpreting the string "Yes" as
            // true, and all other values are false.
            if (rawJson != null && rawJson.ToLower() == "\"yes\"")
                result = true;
            else
                result = false;
        }

        return overrodeValue;
    }
```

That's just hypothetical, of course, but hopefully it gives you an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

In my research I have not been able to figure out a way to do this.  I've looked at [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx), [System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx), and [System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx).  I bet there is a way to do this, and I just haven't been able to figure it out.

**Edit**: I think you might be able to use the [JsonConverterAttribute](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm), but so far I have not been able to get that working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writing a custom `JsonConverter` for a primitive type is pretty straghtforward:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace So16972364JsonDeserializeConverter
{
    class BoolConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override void WriteJson (JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        }

        public override object ReadJson (JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType) {
                case JsonToken.String:
                    if ((string)reader.Value == "")
                        return false;
                    break;
                case JsonToken.Boolean:
                    return reader.Value;
            }
            throw new JsonReaderException("Expected boolean or empty string.");
        }

        public override bool CanConvert (Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(bool);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        const string json = @"
{
    b1: true,
    b2: false,
    b3: ''
}
";

        static void Main ()
        {
            Foo foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings {
                Converters = { new BoolConverter() }
            });
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, Formatting.Indented));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Foo
    {
        public bool b1, b2, b3;
    }
}
```

This code overrides deserialization of all boolean values. If you need this only for specific members, you need to apply `JsonConverterAttribute`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  I modified to suit my needs, and it appears to be working great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is an error in the example above. Instead of

```cs
public override void WriteJson (JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
}
```

there should be

```
public override void WriteJson (JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    writer.WriteValue(value);
}
```

otherwise you will get `StackOverflow` exception! Strangely why nobody hasn't written about it yet.

Comment: yeah, wouldn't that lead to an infinite loop? edit: ah yes, you mention StackOverflow - ty