# How to deserialize json which is sometimes a dictionary and sometimes an empty array?

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

I need to deserialize JSON documents where a particular element is usually a dictionary, but when it contains no data it is an empty array. I have no control over the structure of the JSON. I don't need to serialize, only deserialize. I'm using Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.2, latest stable version.

In the following snippet, `goodJson` illustrates what these documents normally look like, and `badJson` shows what they look like when there are no `details`

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var goodJson = @"
{
    'id': 1,
    'details': {
        'apple': 1,
        'tomato': 4,
        'lettuce': 3,
        'onion': 2
    },
    'bar': { 'A': 5, 'B': 6 }
}";

var badJson = @"
{
    'id': 2,
    'details': [],
    'bar': { 'A': 7, 'B': 8 }
}";

var foo1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(goodJson);
Console.WriteLine($"goodJson: {foo1}");
var foo2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(badJson); // JsonSerializationException
Console.WriteLine($"badJson: {foo2}");

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; } = new Bar();
    public Dictionary<string, int> Details { get; private set; } = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Id: {Id}, Bar: {Bar.A} {Bar.B}, Details count: {Details.Count}";
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
}
```

This throws an exception at the commented line when deserializing `badJson`:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Int32]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array. Path 'details', line 4, position 16.

I understand the error - the deserializer is expecting an object, not an array. I can't change the type of the `Details` property of `Foo` to an array / list type, otherwise `goodJson` won't deserialize.

Having read [Deserializing JSON when sometimes array and sometimes object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5224697/16563198) and [How to deserialize JSON data which sometimes is an empty array and sometimes a string value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17171737/16563198), which are similar to, but not quite the same as my scenario, it seems that overriding `JsonConverter`'s `ReadJson` method is the way to go. So this is how I've gone about doing that:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

public class DictionaryOrArrayConverter<TKey, TValue> : JsonConverter
    where TKey : notnull
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.StartObject:
                var d1 = serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
                Console.WriteLine(d1.GetType().FullName);
                var d2 = (Dictionary<TKey, TValue>)d1;
                Console.WriteLine($"In ReadJson: dictionary has {d2.Count} entries");
                return d2;
            case JsonToken.StartArray:
                reader.Read();
                if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)
                {
                    throw new JsonReaderException("Empty array expected");
                }

                return string.Empty;
        }

        throw new JsonReaderException("Expected object or empty array");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

And I decorate the `Details` property of `Foo` with my converter:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(DictionaryOrArrayConverter<string, int>))]
public Dictionary<string, int> Details { get; private set; } = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

Now the program runs without error, but the `Details` property of `goodJson` is deserializing as an empty dictionary. The console output is as follows:

> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]

> In ReadJson: dictionary has 4 entries

> goodJson: Id: 1, Bar: 5 6, Details count: 0

> badJson: Id: 2, Bar: 7 8, Details count: 0

So I can tell that within the `ReadJson` method the `details` property of `goodJson` is deserializing to an object with a runtime type of `Dictionary<string, int>` with 4 entries, however the object returned by `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` has no entries in its `Details` property.

I guess there must be something wrong with the way I've implemented `ReadJson`, but I can't see what it is.

Comment: I think `JsonSingleOrEmptyArrayConverter<Dictionary<string, int>>` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29450279/3744182) to [Deserialize JSON when a value can be an object or an empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29450279/3744182) should work for you.  The trick is that it makes use of the incoming `existingValue` and populates it if present: `existingValue = existingValue ?? contract.DefaultCreator(); serializer.Populate(reader, existingValue);`

Comment: Yes, `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonSingleOrEmptyArrayConverter<Dictionary<string, int>>))]` works, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/dBgQDm.  Mark as a duplicate?

Comment: Thank you for the link, it demonstrates quite a lot about overriding `JsonConverter` that I wasn't aware of. Not sure why I didn't find that question when I was searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Details` property has a private setter. By default, Newtonsoft.Json/Json.Net won't try assigning the dictionary created and returned by your *DictionaryOrArrayConverter<,>.ReadJson* method due to the setter being private.

Choose one of these options to solve your problem:

1. Make the *Details* setter public.
2. Annotate the *Details* property with a `[JsonPropery]` attribute, which tells Newtonsoft.Json to use the setter regardless of its private accessibility.
3. Since the *Details* property is already intialized with a dictionary instance, that dictionary instance should be available as the parameter *existingValue* in the converter's *ReadJson* method. Therefore, if *existingValue* is not *null*, populate this existing dictionary instance from *existingValue* with the json data and return it instead of creating a new dictionary instance.

Comment: Thank you, option 3 worked for me. The other two options both resulted in a different exception when deserializing `badJson`: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error setting value to 'Details' on 'Foo'.  ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Int32]'. But option 3 worked so I'm happy.

Comment: @sbridewell, ah, that's because your converter returns `string.Empty` when it is seeing an empty json array. And a string is obviously not directly convertible to a dictionary So the error you are seeing there is rather straightforward and self-explanatory. Instead, either clear and return the dictionary provided in _existingValue_, return null, or return a new empty dictionary...

Comment: Ah yes, schoolboy error, returning an empty string when I want an empty dictionary. Thanks for pointing it out, now all 3 options are working :-)

Answer (score 0):

I  usually use a json constructor in this case

```
public class Foo
{
    //... your properties and code

    [JsonConstructor]
    public Foo(JToken Details)
    {
        if (Details.Type != JTokenType.Array)
            this.Details = Details.ToObject<Dictionary<string, int>>();
    }
    public Foo() {}
}
```

output

```
goodJson: Id: 1, Bar: 5 6, Details count: 4
badJson: Id: 2, Bar: 7 8, Details count: 0
```